# What parts of the orientdb Java API are thread safe?

Tags: orientdb

Looking through the source of ORecord class, its looks like its not designed with multi-threading in mind.

Is there a guide for thread-safe use of the API?

Comment: Hi, I found [this](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Java-Multi-Threading.html) about OrientDB multi-threading. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you work with database instance the common approach is to have separate instance of this object for each thread, to simplify this task you may use pool of database objects, for example com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool. 
In general only `OStorage` instances are thread safe, the rest of objects should not be shared between threads, but should be loaded using database instance.

Comment: Hmm... this kinda makes it hard to extract and hold data from the DB. Looking through the ODocument API I see there's a lot of mutable data that not thread safe (e.g. _dirty).

Is there any way to get the DB to deserialize into immutable data structures?

Comment: You may exchange documents/vertices/edges between threads, you can not change them in 2 threads at once. Also you can not share database instances, you should think about them like about connections or sessions.